# While opening Excel file the content is corrupted

Tags: excel, liferay, excel-2010, liferay-6, portal

I am downloading one Excel file using below snippet:

```
   byte[] text = textContent.getText();
   InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(text );
   response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
   ServletResponseUtil.write(response, inputStream);
```

My local server:
When I download Excel in my local machine and open Excel file, there is corrupted data.

My colleague's local server:
When I download in my colleague's local machine, able to see right Excel content which says Excel opening in compatible mode on top of Excel sheet.

UAT:
When I open download from UAT environment, there is corrupted Excel all ????????????? are preset.
This is happening in both my and my colleague local machines.

I can't figure out what is going on, can someone exlain?

Comment: As you tag this "Liferay" but don't mention where this code is at all: Please share a bit more on the location of this code. Is it in a portlet? A servlet (you mention ServletResponseUtil)? Where else?

Comment: Thanks Olaf,  Here  written in servlet which is in liferay project,   What I am  thinking  was forcibly  writing byte text to excel because of that , text got corrupted. I think I need to do some thing like encoding while writing text to excel

Comment: Encoding would be my best guess as well. IMHO this has nothing to do with either Liferay (because it's a servlet) or Excel (because it's just some binary file that doesn't get transmitted the way you expect). Test again with some files with known encodings and see what their transmission results in. Use any non-latin alphabet - it's probably easier to see the results when you just use small text files

Comment: Hi Olaf, can you please let me know hot to set encoding for above code

Comment: more code please. There's an arbitrary textContent object coming in - I have no idea where you got this from, what type it is, etc. Also, check all of the stream-handling code as well as the conversion to byte[] yourself first - there might be options that explicitly accept encodings. I don't know them from the top of my head either, would have to try out.